# How do I format Sweave LaTeX table output to use dollar sign ($)?

Tags: latex, sweave, xtable

Here is sample data:

```
# create table data
year <- c("2010", "2011", "2012")
value <- ("5", "10", "15")
df<-data.frame(year, value)

# print
print(xtable(df,digits=c(0,0,1)))
```

**How can I format the 5, 10, and 15 to display as $5.0, $10.0, and $15.0?**

Possible R packages to assist are `xtable`, `stargazer`, and/or `Hmisc`.

Within `xtable`, the solution may be found in `format.args`: "List of arguments for the `formatC` function. For example, standard German number separators can be specified as `format.args=list(big.mark = "’", decimal.mark = ","))`." - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler to format the `df$value` with dollar format before using the `xtable()` function.  Using your example you have the following (which requires the `scales` library):

```
library(xtable)
library(scales)

# create table data
year <- c("2010", "2011", "2012")
value <- c("5", "10", "15")
df<-data.frame(year, value)

df$value <- dollar(as.numeric(as.character(df$value)))

# print
print(xtable(df))
```

This produces the following LaTeX Code:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.6-0 package
% Fri May 03 10:46:58 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & year & value \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2010 & \$5.00 \\ 
  2 & 2011 & \$10.00 \\ 
  3 & 2012 & \$15.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```